# C# modulus equation return wrong value

Tags: c#, modulus

```
var newPosition = (position - key) % alphabet.Length;
```

When position is 66, key is 7964 and alphabet.length = 91, newPosition is somehow -72, even though it should be 19. Why?

Comment: `%` is not modulus. It is remainder. You could use something like this: `((position - key) % alphabet.Length + alphabet.Length) % alphabet.Length`

Comment: @PetSerAl What's modulus then?

Comment: AFAIK, there are no modulus operator in C#.

Comment: I do want to point out that % is the modulo operator in C#, and (66-7964) % 91 is -72. I wanted to point it out, as the terms are something I often confuse, especially as they're both abbreviated to 'mod.' Worse, there's a number of different meanings involved for both terms mathematically:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472856/

Answer (score 0):

Be aware % is actually not a modulus its a remainder

```
static decimal modulus(decimal a, decimal b)
{
  return a - b * Math.Floor(a / b);
}

...

Console.WriteLine( nfmod(66-7964 , 91));
```

**Ouput**

```
19
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t6OEJz)

Answer (score 0):

Use / for module

```
var newPosition = (position - key) / alphabet.Length;
```

Comment: That still returned a negative number

Answer (score 0):

```
((position - key) % alphabet.Length + alphabet.Length) % alphabet.Length
```

Did the trick